# Help with shell script reading data usage in a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm confused on how to get the data usage information into the variables to determine if the file size are acceptable. **How do I make the variable and direct it to the rest of the script?**

Write a script (called `passwd_size.sh`) that does these tasks:

- Find the size of the `/etc/passwd` file
- If the size is greater than 2000 bytes, display a message that the file exceeds size, otherwise, display message that the file is within the size limit.

---

```
du -c "/etc/passwd"
num=0
if [ $num -gt 2000 ];
then
echo "File exceeds size limit."
fi
if [ $num -lt 2000 && -eq 2000  ];
then
echo "File is within size limit."
fi
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Isn't size in lines more interesting?

Comment: @JacobVlijm probably, but this does look homework. Homework doesn't care. :/

Comment: @muru Ah, I am too naive :)

Comment: Instead of using two separate `if` statements, you could just use one, with an `else` part to it. Also your output from the du command isn't being assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh

file=/etc/passwd

minimum=2000

actual=$(wc -c <"$file")

if [ $actual -ge $minimum ]; then

echo The file size is bigger $minimum bytes

else

echo The file size is less  $minimum bytes

fi
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but are you able to use: du -h is the script?

Comment: Try   du  -b "/etc/passwd"